# app.get() function not getting called in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

So I am starting a node.js app, and familiarizing myself with the basics. I have installed express, and am using the get function to create a route and send a response.
However, on entering the webpage on the browser, the page keeps loading and does not give a response. Any idea on what I am doing wrong here? Even the request body does not show up on the logs, so it looks like its not entering the get function.

Below is the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
  res.send("XYZ Homepage");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: `bodyparser.json` should be `bodyparser.json()`. Even better, use `app.use(express.json())` since `body-parser` is now [built-in to Express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json)

Comment: Useful tip, thank you. However, the response is still not going through for some reason. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It wasn't meant as a _"useful tip"_. You had (and still have) a middleware function that never completes. If you've changed your code, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70965505/edit). Note that any changes to your script will require you to restart the Express app

Comment: Got it. All I did now was remove the middleware function itself, and have the simple get(), still doesn't send the response. I have nodemon installed as well, so I am assuming that helps automatically restart the app?

Comment: Seems odd, looks to be working fine after creating another app.

Comment: Have you tried restarting nodemon?